# Call specific method on static const member

Tags: c++

Here is the idea: I have a class that has some member variable(s), say `x`. This class also has a method, `A()`, which does not modify the member variable(s), but returns info about them. There is also a method `B()` which *does* modify the member variable(s). So basically, this is the setup:

```
class Class
{
    int x;
    Class(int x) : x(x) { }

    int A() { return x; /* info about x */ }
    void B() { x++; /* updates x! */ }
}
```

So far so good. But now I want to have some special version of this class that will be used throughout the project, and I want it to have a specific set of member variable(s), say, x = 3. My idea was to add a `const static Class mySpecialCase` member to `Class`, and just refer to `Class::mySpecialCase` whenever necessary.

The problem however, is that I need to call `A()` on this object, to fetch some information, but do not want `B()` to be called on this object, since it would modify `x`, which would affect all future usage of the 'special case'.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: What about `static int A() { return mySpecialCase.x; }` ?

Comment: @leemes The problem is that I have to generalize this for multiple member variables and multiple special cases.

Comment: I guess I misunderstood. I thought you want to write `Class::A()` which should then "forward" to the static member.

Comment: I don't understand this idea about a "special case". Surely you're just asking about a read-only instance with a particular value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's already illegal to call `Class::mySpecialCase.B()`, since `mySpecialCase` is `const` and `B()` is not a `const` member.  You just need to make it possible to call `A()`, by making `A()` a `const` member function:

```
class Class
{
    int x;
public:
    Class(int x) : x(x) { }

    static const Class mySpecialCase;

    int A() const { return x; /* info about x */ }
    void B() { x++; /* updates x! */ }
};

// In class.cpp:
const Class Class::mySpecialCase{3};
```

Answer (score 2):

> The problem however, is that I need to call A() on this object, to fetch some information, but do not want B() to be called on this object, since it would modify x,

Declare the object and `B()` as `const` but not `A()`:

```
 class Class {
     public:
          [...]
          int A();
          void B() const;
 };

 // Initialize const object.
 const Class specialCase(3);
```

Calling `specialCase.A()` will be a compile error, but `specialCase.B()` is still okay because the `const` modifier indicates to the compiler this method does not alter the object.

Answer (score 0):

> So far so good.

Not really. `A` should be `const`:

```
int A() const { return x; /* info about x */ }
```

> But now I want to have some special version of this class

By *version*, you mean *instance*, right?

Add a static member function returning a reference to a static local instance of `Class`:

```
#include <iostream>

class Class
{
public:
    int x;
    Class(int x) : x(x) { }

    int A() const { return x; /* info about x */ }
    void B() { x++; /* updates x! */ }

    static Class &SpecialInstance()
    {
        static Class instance(3);
        return instance;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Class a(1);
    Class b(2);
    Class c = Class::SpecialInstance();

    std::cout << c.A() << "\n";
}
```